# Python- need to append characters to the beginning and end of each line in text file

Tags: python

I should preface that I am a complete Python Newbie.

Im trying to create a script that will loop through a directory and its subdirectories looking for text files.  When it encounters a text file it will parse the file and convert it to NITF XML and upload to an FTP directory.

At this point I am still working on reading the text file into variables so that they can be inserted into the XML document in the right places.  An example to the text file is as follows.

```
Headline
Subhead
By A person
Paragraph text.
```

And here is the code I have so far:

```
with open("path/to/textFile.txt") as f:
    #content = f.readlines()
    head,sub,auth = [f.readline().strip() for i in range(3)]
    data=f.read()
pth = os.getcwd()

print head,sub,auth,data,pth
```

My question is: how do I iterate through the body of the text file(data) and wrap each line in HTML P tags?  For example;

`<P>line of text in file </P> <P>Next line in text file</p>`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
output_format = '<p>{}</p>\n'.format
with open('input') as fin, open('output', 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines( output_format(line.strip()) for line in fin )
```

Comment: Careful, `fin.readlines()` still preserves the newline at the end of each line, and I don't think that `writelines` adds a newline.  This is probably OK since we're doing HTML here, but it's not strictly correct with what OP is asking.

Comment: Also, why not `map(output_format,fin)`.  No need for `readlines`.

Comment: @mgilson completely agree - quite an impressive brain burp on my part

Comment: Actually ... `fout.writelines( output_format(x) for x in fin )` might be the most succint way to do this completely lazily :)

Comment: I suppose I should add that it's the most succint way to do it completely lazily in py2k **and** py3k.  (`map` is just as lazy in py3k).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I dont think the newline symbols matter since we are outputting HTML.  I'm fairly certain that the text will wrap on the display end.

Comment: @user1789778 Thank mgilson - he's corrected my currently not firing on all cylinders brain!

Comment: I should have mentioned it in the original post, Im a complete Noob when it comes to PY.  Can you give me a little bit of a breakdown on your original post.  I don’t completely understand what that code accomplishes.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('infile') as fin, open('outfile',w) as fout:
    for line in fin:
        fout.write('<P>{0}</P>\n'.format(line[:-1])  #slice off the newline.  Same as `line.rstrip('\n')`.

#Only do this once you're sure the script works :)
shutil.move('outfile','infile')  #Need to replace the input file with the output file
```

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that you want to write the new content back to the original file:

```
with open('path/to/textFile.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

with open('path/to/textFile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in content:
        f.write('<p>' + line.strip() + '</p>\n')
```

Comment: You might just want a `line.rstrip('\n')`.

Comment: I'm assuming `line.strip()` is safe here, since the OP uses it already and whitespace is ignored by HTML.

Answer (score 0):

in you case, you should probably replace

```
data=f.read()
```

with:

```
data = '\n'.join("<p>%s</p>" % l.strip() for l in f)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `data=f.readlines()` here,

and then iterate over data and try something like this:

```
for line in data:
   line="<p>"+line.strip()+"</p>"
   #write line+'\n' to a file or do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

append the

and <\p> for each line

ex:

```
     data_new=[]
     data=f.readlines()
     for lines in data:
          data_new.append("<p>%s</p>\n" % data.strip().strip("\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `fileinput` module to modify one or more files in-place, with optional backup file creation if desired (see its [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput) for details). Here's it being used to process one file.

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input('testinput.txt', inplace=1):
    print '<P>'+line[:-1]+'<\P>'
```

The `'testinput.txt'` argument could also be a sequence of two or more file names instead of just a single one, which could be useful especially if you're using `os.walk()` to generate the list of files in the directory and its subdirectories to process (as you probably should be doing).